# Create a Jet Database Only using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to Create a Database that i can publish with a VB.Net Program. I did it just fine Linking MS Access but the problem is what if the user doesn't have Access. So i asked around a bit and one of my teachers said to use a jet database.

Is there a better option for sending a database that the user needs to populate when i publish?

if not!

How can i create a Jet database only in VB.net?

Using this option I will of course need to send 2 programs along one to Populate the data and one to Read and do its job.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Read (The Microsoft Jet Database Engine is a database engine on which several Microsoft products have been built.) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine

Answer (score 0):

If it's a fairly simple database that you are going to be using then you might also want to take a look at sql compact edition.  I won't say that this is superior to jet databases but you might find distribution easier.

Comment: Alright thanks For the idea m8 i will look into that as well cause even with Jet i am hitting a brick wall!